# How to force install el7 package instead of el8 on centos7?

Tags: visual-studio-code, centos7

I encounter an issue after a system update. code have been update with el8 package on my centos7. Since then, code interface is freezing. I can't succeed in installing again el7 package.

I assume microsoft yumrepos have been update to point on el8 repo. Is there a yumrepos url for el7 package?

regards

Comment: I'm not sure how to set up the yum config for that but you could try downloading an RPM from [the repo here](https://packages.microsoft.com/yumrepos/vscode/) and install it manually. It looks like 1.55.0 is the last one with el7 packages.

Answer (score 0):

well, it appears that all the rpm el8 are stored in the same repo as the el7. I just had to specify the last el7 version to install it.